# Is there a way to check whether a .so has been compiled with -Bsymbolic-functions flag?

Tags: linker, dynamic-loading

My application loads custom code using `dlopen` on the fly. 
For common symbols, the global symbol table is used by default.

However, I want to provide the functionality where - if the user has linked their so with `-Bsymbolic-functions`, I pass the `RTLD_DEEPBIND` flag to the `dlopen` function.

Is there a way I can programmatically know whether a .so is linked with `-Bsymbolic-functions` or not using C ?

Comment: My reading of the documentation on `-Bsymbolic-functions` and `RTLD_DEEPBIND` suggests to me that `RTLD_DEEPBIND` would do nothing for a library that had been linked with `-Bsymbolic-functions` because such a library would not contain any references to functions defined within itself: they would all have been already resolved to internal locations at link time!

Comment: @Celada , the behavior I am seeing is that if deliberately just pass `RTLD_LAZY` with a library that is deep bound, then the symbols are not loaded from within the .so in case of conflicts.  I have to pass `RTLD_DEEPBIND | RTLD_LAZY ` for such cases.

Comment: Hmm, I would have thought that couldn't happen because `-Bsymbolic-functions` would resolve internal references in a way that the runtime dynamic linker can't see them, can't even know that exist. So I have no idea what's going on and I hope someone with lots of ELF expertise will come along to help you. Good question, +1.

Comment: Your _question_ accidentally just saved me, I was using `RTLD_DEEPBIND` to solve a problem of using wrong symbols (symbol inside .so was not being used because a different symbol with the same name was loaded earlier). I didn't know about `-Bsymbolic-functions`, just learned about it now, and it seems to be a much better solution ;)

Comment: if nm says no symbols, you can try with the -D like: > nm -D libxxx.so | grep "my_routine_name"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the standard ELF program dump:

`dump -Lv libxxx.so | grep SYMBOLIC`

Comment: Is there a way I can get the same information using an API from C ? My question is specifically looking for a C API.

Comment: Did you check libelf? It may not be vailable in a  GNU environment but it is the original ELF library from UNIX, OSS and free to use.

Comment: libelf is available on GNU systems and AFAIK is a part of the GCC suite (otherwise GCC would not be able to build binaries :) )

Comment: I am not sure whether the GNU lib has the same content. as the Sun/AT&T lib. You may like to have a look into the man pages: http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man3elf/

Comment: libelf helped me to an extent , I will update the post soon with details.

Answer (score 1):

There is a command named **nm**

> nm - list symbols from object files

You can use the command

```
nm Absolute_path_of_.so_file_name | grep -i -Bsymbolic-functions
```

Comment: Is there a way I can get the same information using an API from C ? My question is specifically looking for a C API...